# How to handshake jaspersoft after success login of keycloak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, keycloak, jasperserver

My project is an AngularJS UI application, we have an CAS authentication system for login and we call `/jasperserver-pro/flow.html?_flowId=homeFlow` API. This API will redirects to jaspersoft login page and it has `jspring_method` in API response header.

We have changed CAS to keycloak. I am calling `protocol/openid-connect/token` post API to get the token. I am getting the access_token .

Which is the right API to send keycloak `access_token` to jaspersoft server in order to initiate jasper communication.

I read a document it says we have `j_spirng_method` url but this method is getting from response header of `flow.html`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with http://host:port/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_security__check?ticket=access_token
In the installed jasper server if the param name is provided as 'ticket' . Change it accordingly and restart the jasper server.